# Cannot delete GKE ingress rules

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I have created rule.
Now I see this message in Ingress description:

```
Error during GC: error running load balancer garbage collection routine:
 googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'forwardingRule': 'k8s2-fr-nbxe481u-default-kaf.XXX-XXXX.XX-3r69b1ge'. Must be a match of regex '[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?|[1-9][0-9]{0,19}', invalid
```

Nothing happens after attempt to remove this one in GKE web console.

`kubectl` hangs on:
`kubectl delete ingress this_ingress`

Answer (score 6):

From the error message you are sharing I can notice you are using dot (.) in the ingress name which is still valid for k8s but not for the GCE networking resources. Thus this is stuck. [A fix](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/pull/1147) is found ongoing for invalid frontend resource name.

However, as of now you can try the workaround of removing the finalizer in the ingress by editing the yaml file and then try to remove the ingress.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 6):

To be more specific on removing the finalizer in the ingress is to delete the following lines in the ingress yaml. After deleting these lines the ingresses should be removed without further issues.

```
  finalizers:
  - networking.gke.io/ingress-finalizer-V2
```

Comment: Thanks! Had the same issue and this solved it immediately.